# Restore backup.ab file on Amazon Fire TV Stick?

Tags: restore, amazon-fire-tv-stick

I'm trying to restore a backup file onto an Amazon Fire TV Stick 2 using `adb restore backup.ab`, however, the restore confirmation doesn't come up on the Fire TV Stick. The device is rooted and currently have TWRP.

Is there a way to force restore without a confirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the device is rooted you can manually restore the backup.

1. On a PC extract the backup file using [Android Backup extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor). 
   This will convert the backup to a TAR archive.
2. (optional) extract the APK files (if the backup contains not only app data) and install them via adb.
3. Upload the TAR archive to your device via `adb push` and untar it.
4. Copy the files you want to recover into the right directories using `adb shell` and root permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than trying to find an old version of adb, it's easier to add quotes to the arguments to adb backup :

```
adb backup "-apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\NAME\backup.ab"
```

Comment: Adding quotes didn't help.